# Dynamically select a column using month and year, then sumif the values based on criteria in another column

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

Here is an image of what I'm trying to achieve:

I am not well-versed in creating my own VBA script, but can understand code written by someone else if given time to dissect it. If this objective can be resolved without VBA, that would be my preference. I've explored using `INDEX` and `MATCH` but have gotten nowhere. Any suggestions?

I'm using Excel 2013.
[image: Corrected image here]

Comment: Please provide the image and detailed information on what you wish to acquire.

Comment: My objective and examples are found in the image.

Comment: The column select shouldn't be too bad, considering you're using n=12 entries per year... you could technically use 0 = 2018, 1 = 2019, etc., *n+n to find the correct column, only needing to read the Month row.  Regarding the other column criteria to sum... you'd need to give more information.

Comment: Thanks for responding, Cyril. What other information do you need? I just want to sum all the "Plan" cells for the month and year selected. I will also do the same for "Actual". The "criteria in another column" refers to the "Plan"s and "Actual"s in column C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would "cheat"

I have my months list was in `AI1:AI12`, and year list in `AJ1:AJ2` (for the dropdowns in A1 and B1 respectively). Move them elsewhere for more years.

Then in `A2`:

```
=MATCH(A1,AI1:AI12,0)
```

In `B2`:

```
=IF(MATCH(B1,AJ1:AJ2,0)=1,0,12 *( MATCH(B1,AJ1:AJ2,0)-1))
```

In `D1O` drag across to `AA10`:

```
=SUMIF($C$3:$C$8,"Plan",D3:D8)
```

Note: You could remove hardcoded "Plan" and reference a cell instead.

Result in `C1` with

```
=OFFSET(D10,,B2+A2-1,1,1)
```

[image: DATA]

You are basically using a formula to determine how far to offset from month 1, year1 to get the current month and year conditional sum in row 10.

Comment: QHarr: Thanks so much for your response. It worked for me! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Example of finding the correct column, as described in my comment (*untested code*):

```
arr = array("Jan","Feb") 'you can do the rest
x = 2018 'first year in question, to make the math easier
s = 4 'column your first month is in
y = cells(1,2).value - x
z = application.match(left(cells(1,1).value,3),arr,0)
'all that gets you to:
c = s+(y*12)+z
```

You can then use the final column number, *c*, to do your Application.Sumifs() where you specify actual/plan as one of your criteria.

Comment: Cyril, thanks for your response. I chose to use another solution as that one kept me out of VBA. Once I get better at VBA, I'll definitely consider solutions such as yours. Thanks again!